# Friend function can't access the private variables

Tags: c++, friend-function

I am trying to overload the `<<` operator to display a matrix, but it says that none of my private members can be accessed.

In my header file, I have:

```
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const matrix& out);
```

and for my private members I have:

```
private:
int p_rowSize;
int p_rowSize;
vector<vector<double> > p_matrix;
```

In my implementation file, I have the following code, and am unsure how I am supposed to get it to work:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const matrix& out)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < p_rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < p_colSize; j++)
        {
            cout << "[" << p_matrix[i][j] << "] ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

It is telling me that `p_colSize`, `p_rowSize`, and `p_matrix` are all undefined here, but not in any other function that I've written.

Comment: Don't you mean `out.p_colSize`, etc?

Comment: Note when your function does not have access you would get different compilation error, rather than undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A friend function has access to the data members, but since it's still a free function (rather than a member function) you need to specify which object you're accessing using `out.p_rowSize`, etc.

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const matrix& out)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < out.p_rowSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < out.p_colSize; j++)
        {
            os << "[" << out.p_matrix[i][j] << "] ";
        }
        os << endl;
    }
    return os;
}
```

Some notes:

1. You should output to `os`, not `cout`.
2. You forgot to return a value from the function, so I added `return os;` for you.

Comment: As your answer already covers everything mine does plus more I deleted mine, you can remove mention to me.